# Rounding Issue with a number containing "`"

Tags: number-representation, rounding, output-formatting

I would like to round a number saved in a weird format  (I have no idea what the "`" means, could someone explain?)  to 3 digits:

```
Round[0.7000000000000001`, 0.001]
```

However, the output is just the same as the input. What is going on here?

Comment: Numbers are represented in binary, not decimal. Classic reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers represent floating point numbers in binary, not decimal. (Mandatory reading: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) Some numbers are exactly representable in decimal, but not binary. It is the same situation as 1/3 not being representable in decimal. `0.333333` is not *exactly* 1/3.

Therefore, if we take:

```
r = 0.001;
x = Round[0.7000000000000001`, r];
```

you might expect x/r to be exactly 700. But it is not because the numbers I wrote here are simply not exactly representable in binary. There will be necessarily be small errors when they are converted to binary.

Demonstration:

```
ratio1 = FromDigits[RealDigits[x, 2], 2]/FromDigits[RealDigits[r, 2], 2]
(* 807045053224792960/1152921504606847 *)

ratio2 = FromDigits[RealDigits[0.7, 2], 2]/FromDigits[RealDigits[r, 2], 2]
(* 807045053224792832/1152921504606847 *)
```

`ratio1` is in fact closer to 700 than `ratio2`, thus `Round` was justified in returning `x` and not `0.7000000000000000`.

```
Abs[700 - ratio1] < Abs[700 - ratio2]
(* True *)

N[Abs[700 - ratio1], 20]
(* 5.2041704279304211749*10^-14 *)

N[Abs[700 - ratio2], 20]
(* 5.8980598183211439982*10^-14 *)
```

Note that we can still opt to work with rational (exact numbers) rather than inexact numbers:

```
Round[0.7000000000000001`, 1/1000]
(* 7/10 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how can I convert 0.7000000000000001` to 0.70  such that I can continue calculating with 0.70 ? Is that not possible?

Comment: @Luke It is not possible with floating point representations.  This is not a limitation of Mathematica. It is a limitation of the representation, and will apply to any other system using standard binary representation. Only some financial programs use decimal representations. To get _exact_ results, you can use rational numbers, as I show in the update to the answer. This will make numerical computations extremely slow, which may or may not matter depending on your application.

Comment: @Luke Do carefully consider if you actually need exact numbers. Why is `0.7000000000000001` not close enough to 0.7 for you? Exact representations are what Mathematica excels at, but they are not usually the correct solution to this problem. If you need higher precision, you can use that. Do you really need "infinite" precision, and if yes, why? It only makes sense when doing symbolic calculations.

Comment: I have a huge table of data and I want to find specific values which are grouped together by matching patterns using Position[list, {1,2,3,4,0.7}] for example. Since 0.7 is in reality 0.7000000000000001 is doesn't match the pattern. But using 7/10 instead works for me! Thanks!

Comment: @Luke This is a typical case of what they call an "XY Problem" ... http://xyproblem.info/ If you had asked _that_ we could have told you to match `x_ /; x==0.7` instead if `0.7`. Trying to use exact numbers is not the right solution.

Comment: thanks ;) now I learned two important things instead of one, so I am happy ;)